# Is it possible to count characters for a regex lookahead?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to validate an expressions similar to this:

```
SEN 3 00000001 HT 12.60 39.50
```

using the pattern `SEN \\d{1} \\w{8} \\w{1,2} ([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*){1,2}`. The pattern mostly works. The group that is returned is

```
SEN 3 00000001 HT 12.60
```

with the `39.50` lost. I am figuring the cause is because of the last quantity condition (`{1,2}`) in my pattern is satisfied with just the `12.60`.

Is there a way to set the quantity needed to satisfy `([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)` based on the character quantity of `\\w{1,2}` using lookaheads?

Comment: Replace `\\d{1}` with just `\\d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it :)

The error you've made is leaving the space OUTSIDE of the group that is being repeated at the end. Since there is a space between 12.60 and 39.50, there will be no match besides for the 12.60.

Try this regular expression instead:

```
SEN \\d{1} \\w{8} \\w{1,2}( [-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*){1,2}
```

A few optimizations:

- Replace () with (?:) since it will be overwritten when quantified, unless that is by design
- Replace \d{1} with \d, they're the same thing.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/jQ7sP2

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the catch! I doubt I ever would have found that; it was so subtle.